# Tibco Spotfire webplayer, set a document property via the url

Tags: spotfire, tibco

I am trying to do something simple in Tibco Spotfire, to try and set a document property in webplayer by specifying a property in the url.  I cannot get this to work.

I have created a document property called 'test' which is simply a string

[image: Image of document property]

I have then created an input text control bound to that document property

[image: Image of input text property binding]

I would expect that if I opened that report in webplayer with a url prepended with &configurationBlock=test%3D"helloworld" then the input text would be populated with the value helloworld.  However, it is not.

[image: Image showing value is not set via url]

This seems to be a reasonably simple thing to get working, I have tried what I think is every possible variant of encoding the data to no effect.  Is there something I am doing wrong that could make this work.

Answer (score 0):

you are going to hate this answer :)

you need to put a semicolon at the end of the parameter assignment. so you should have:

```
http://example.com/Spotfire/stuff?configurationBlock=test=helloworld;
```